# JDK 8 random crashes on linux

Tags: java, linux

I experience random crashes using JDK 8_20 64bit for linux. It's the same with Netbeans, IDEA and Eclipse or hello world programs. It's the same with JDK 8_25 64bit. Anyone? Problematic frame is always the same.

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

 SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f267b005060, pid=28116, tid=139803312420608

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_20-b26) (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.20-b23 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  0x00007f267b005060

Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
  http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

Comment: what is your underlying operating system?

Comment: OS is Ubuntu 14.04.1

Answer (score 5):

With such a wide spectrum of things crashing, I suspect that it is something systemic with your Java installation.  Maybe you installed from a corrupted installer (or whatever), or maybe the installation has been "messed with".

And if it isn't that, then the next place to look is either:

- some JVM bug that is particular to your platform (e.g. OS, window manager, video device, etc), or
- hardware errors (!).

The best thing I can suggest is that you enable core dumping (per the instructions), and see what you get.  [This page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/crashes-137240.html) may help you diagnose the dump ... as may Googling.

And if you have a support contract, call Oracle for help.

Answer (score 0):

It may raised because of limitation in ulimit

use this:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```